# VS code API: How to get thread id on which debugger is paused in multithread program

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger, vscode-api

I am currently building a VS code extension to visualize C# variables and datatables. And I have successfully achieved this in single threaded application by calling these in sequence:

1. [Thread request](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/specification#Requests_Threads)
2. [StackTrace request](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/specification#Requests_StackTrace)
3. [Scope request](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/specification#Requests_Scopes)
4. [Variable request](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/specification#Requests_Variables)
   via
   DAP([Debug Adapter Protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/specification)).

- But I am currently facing issues in multi threaded C# application, As it returns multiple threads and I can't figure which thread id I should pass in stack trace request. Here is my code to get threads and other request.
- Can I get active thread id on which breakpoint is paused? or do I have to check for all threads? and How?

This is what i have done for single threaded C# application in javascript.

```
// Get Active Debug Session
const session = vscode.debug.activeDebugSession;

// Get Thread
const threadResponse = await session.customRequest('threads');
const threadId = threadResponse.threads[0].id;

// Get StackFrame
const stackResponse = await session.customRequest('stackTrace', { threadId: threadId, startFrame: 0 });
const frameId = stackResponse.stackFrames[0].id;

// Get Scope
const scopeResponse = await session.customRequest('scopes', { frameId: frameId });
const variableReference = scopeResponse.scopes[0].variablesReference;

// Get Variable
const variableResponse = await session.customRequest('variables', { variablesReference: variableReference });
const variables = variableResponse.variables;
```